# How to specify 2 scopes in 1 line in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a project where I specify a dependency twice but in 2 different scopes, like so:

```
compileOnly "myDependency"
testImplementation "myDependency"
```

I would like to specify it once, in one line, like so:

```
compileOnly+testImplementation "myDependency"
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities:

##### 1. Using Groovy's `with`

```
dependencies {
   "myDependency".with { compileOnly(it); testImplementation(it) }
}
```

##### 2. Registering a new configuration

```
configurations {
    register('compileAndTest')
    compileOnly { extendsFrom compileAndTest }
    testImplementation { extendsFrom compileAndTest }
}

dependencies {
    compileAndTest('myDependency')
}
```

##### 3. Switch to Kotlin and use an extension function

```
fun DependencyHandler.compileAndTest(dependency: String) {
   compileOnly(dependency)
   testImplementation(dependency)
}

dependencies {
   compileAndTest("myDependency")
}
```